# Why is vscode not identifying .c?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

when I create a c file, vscode isn't identifying it but when i type .cc it does idetify c++. [here is the ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ0Va.png) I am new to programming i cant figure this out.
tips or help please

Comment: depends on if there is an extension that supports `*.c` files, have you installed the `ms-vscode.cpptools` extension for C and C++

Comment: I do have the extension installed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

After writing the code, right-click on the program, as shown below. Click on the Run Code option or press Ctrl + Alt + N from the button.

Comment: Umm ...........

Comment: probably for a different question